# jQuery .val() isnt picking out the value of the innerText

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, input, dialog

I have this method:

```
$(".btnUpdateOnlineCommunity").click(function () {
    var communityDiv = $(this).closest("div");

    var communityName = communityDiv.find('.lblOnlineCommunityDescription');
    var descriptionName = communityDiv.find('.pOnlineCommunityDetails');
    var communityLink = communityDiv.find('.linkOnlineCommunity');

    $('.txtCommunityName').val(communityName.val());
    $('.txtCommunityDescription').text(descriptionName.val());
    $('.txtCommunityLink').val(communityLink.val());

    var communityId = $(communityDiv).data("id");
    $(".dvCommunityDialog").data("communityId", communityId).dialog("open");
});
```

`txtCommunityName`, `txtCommunityDescription` and `txtCommunityLink` are all controls withing `dvCommunityDialog` which is a jQuery dialog. The problem is when the dialog opens the value of `communityName`, `descriptionName` and `communityLink` do not appear in the controls, but when I write it this way  `$('.txtCommunityLink').val('Test');` I get `Test` in the control, what is the problem here ?

**HTML**

```
<p runat="server" id="pInterest">
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAddInterest" CssClass="btnAddCommunity" Text="Add Interest" OnClientClick="return false;" />
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptOnlineCommunities" OnItemDataBound="rptOnlineCommunities_ItemDataBound">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <div id="tblUseCommunities" class="dvOnlineCommunityMain">
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div runat="server" id="dvOnlineCommunity" class="dvOnlineCommunity">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblOnlineCommunityDescription" CssClass="lblOnlineCommunityDescription"></asp:Label>
                <p runat="server" id="pOnlineCommunityDetails" class="pOnlineCommunityDetails"></p>
                <a runat="server" id="linkOnlineCommunity" class="linkOnlineCommunity" target="_blank"></a>
                <p>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpdateOnlineCommunity" CssClass="btnUpdateOnlineCommunity" Text="Update" OnClientClick="return false;" />
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDeleteOnlineCommunity" CssClass="btnDeleteOnlineCommunity" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return false;" />
                </p>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <div runat="server" id="dvOnlineCommunity" class="dvOnlineCommunity">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblOnlineCommunityDescription" CssClass="lblOnlineCommunityDescription"></asp:Label>
                <p runat="server" id="pOnlineCommunityDetails" class="pOnlineCommunityDetails"></p>
                <a runat="server" id="linkOnlineCommunity" class="linkOnlineCommunity" target="_blank"></a>
                <p>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpdateOnlineCommunity" CssClass="btnUpdateOnlineCommunity" Text="Update" OnClientClick="return false;" />
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDeleteOnlineCommunity" CssClass="btnDeleteOnlineCommunity" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return false;" />
                </p>
            </div>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </div>                   
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</p>

<div class="dvCommunityDialog">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="dialogControlLabels">Title/Name:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtCommunityName" class="txtCommunityName" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="dialogControlLabels">Description:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea id="txtCommunityDescription" class="txtCommunityDescription"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="dialogControlLabels">Link:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtCommunityLink" class="txtCommunityLink" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: The question isn't very clear, but going by the title, the answer is obvious, `val()` gets the value of elements that have a value attribute, it **does not** get the innerText.

Comment: Show us the relevant HTML source

Comment: If @adeneo is right, then you're looking for `.text()` instead of `.val()`

Answer (score 1):

Given your HTML I can see that the elements you're trying to retrieve the `value` of are of type `label`, `p` and `a` which do not have `value` attribute to read. You should instead get their `text()`:

```
var $communityName = communityDiv.find('.lblOnlineCommunityDescription');
var $descriptionName = communityDiv.find('.pOnlineCommunityDetails');
var $communityLink = communityDiv.find('.linkOnlineCommunity');

$('.txtCommunityName').val($communityName.text());
$('.txtCommunityDescription').text($descriptionName.text());
$('.txtCommunityLink').val($communityLink.text());
```

Comment: Thank you Rory... This worked, Just not used to front end dev, not too sure when to use Val or Text

Comment: Glad to help. Use `val()` to retrieve the `value` attribute of the element, and use `text()` to retrieve the `innerHTML`